Loosen overly specific transitive dependency requirement in Cargo.toml
Consider the following dependency situation. My crate depends on two other crates, parser-foo and parser-bar, both of which depend on parser-core. The parser-core crate links to a native library, so only one version of it can be pulled in.
Say parser-foo depends on parser-core >=0.4, and parser-bar depends on parser-core ^0.2. Cargo rightly complains that it cannot satisfy the dependency requirements as those ranges are incompatible.
But actually, I know that parser-bar would work totally fine with parser-core version 0.4 without any change to its source code. The maintainer of parser-bar was just overly specific in their Cargo.toml.
Can I convince Cargo to compile parser-bar with the newer parser-core? Ideally without resorting to pointing parser-bar to a git patch.
